# JS variable is only assigned when firefox debugger used

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-debugger

I have a piece of Javascript code. 
I have a variable that I assign to be an array of read in values as written below.

```
var varA = getRowData("document.csv");
```

It is assigned the return value of that function. The return value is correct and holds the right array, however the variable comes back undefined unless I use a debugger to pause on the above line and follow it through. If I follow the assignment through it comes back fine.

I have noticed when I don't use the debugger it comes back with the varA undefined at the top of my console messages and then has the return value logged at the bottom. Whereas when I use the debugger varA is at the bottom and the return value logged is at the top of the console messages.

I use window.onload to call the function that declares varA as above. If someone could point me in the right direction as to why it might run differently when using the debugger to what it would normally that would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the actual code so we have some context as to what's going on?

Comment: Is getRowData() is asynchronous?